# Ways of showing rating with stars in blade. laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question.
I am trying to show ratings in web.
this is the way that I am thinking to implement. I think it is too long.

```
@if ($nr>=1 && $nr<=1)
{
<div class="rating">
      <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-star-0"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
</div><!-- end rating -->
}
@elseif ($nr>=2 && $nr<=2)
{
<div class="rating">
     <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
     <span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
     <span><i class="fa fa-star-0"></i></span>
     <span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
     <span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
</div><!-- end rating -->
}
```

and so on...

Is there another way? A shorter one ?
I have seen android programmers that do it only by using functions. What about in web or in laravel?

Comment: Blade doesn't use curly braces for `@if`, `@elseif` etc., so you should remove those unless you actually want them to appear in your application. As an aside, I notice you're fairly new and many of your questions don't have accepted answers. StackOverflow isn't just a support forum - if any answers solve your question(s), remember to mark them as accepted so that others can benefit from them in the future. If you find a solution to questions yourself, it's also acceptable to post your own answer and accept that if the others don't work.

Comment: You can see this simple example: https://www.cssscript.com/simple-5-star-rating-system-with-css-and-html-radios/

Answer (score 6):

You can do it without a loop if you like.

```
<div class="rating">
    {!! str_repeat('<span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>', $nr) !!}
    {!! str_repeat('<span><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>', 5 - $nr) !!}
</div>
```

Comment: This could use the Blade syntax.

Comment: @Camilo does Blade have a str_repeat type thing? I couldn't remember, been a little while since I used Laravel.

Comment: No, but you could use curly brackets instead of opening the PHP tag and echoing. Something like `{{ str_repeat('<span><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>', $nr) }}`.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you're saying. Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but you need to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}` to enable HTML output. Please fix it.

Comment: @Taha oh yeah, I think you're right. Thanks! I'll correct it when I get back to my desk.

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for the answer, I copied and pasted it to one of my projects ;)

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a bit late but here's my way of doing it.

In Laravel 6+ | 7+ blade (may work on earlier versions also) with Font Awesome 5 and with a base of 5 (five) stars do display:

Note: the `$review->average` comes as a float with two decimal points: e.g. **4.70**

```
{{--Start Rating--}}
@for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    @if (floor($review->average) - $i >= 1)
        {{--Full Start--}}
        <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"> </i>
    @elseif ($review->average - $i > 0)
        {{--Half Start--}}
        <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"> </i>
    @else
        {{--Empty Start--}}
        <i class="far fa-star text-warning"> </i>
    @endif
@endfor
{{--End Rating--}}
```

I hope it still helps anyone finding a solution for float-based rating values.

Answer (score 1):

//convert the star achieved to integer

```
<?php $stars = $rating; $stars = round($stars,0)?>
```

//loop through the stars the user has, lets say you had 3 stars out of 5 this loop gets the 3 stars in greeen colour while the next loop gets the star in white meaning lost star rating

```
@for($i= 1;$i<=$stars;$i++)
    @if($i>5)
        @break(0);
    @endif
    <i class="fa fa-star" style="color: @if($stars<3) yellow @else green @endif"></i>
@endfor
//loop to get the star the user lost
    @if(5-$stars > 0)
        @for($i= 1;$i<=5-$stars;$i++)
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        @endfor
    @endif
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could work

```
<div class="rating">
    @for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
        <span><i class="fa fa-star{{ $nr <= $i ? '-o' : '' }}"></i></span>
    @endfor
</div>
```

Comment: he is also asking to get the lost stars check his code above

Comment: so the achieved star is higlighted let say green whhile the lost should be plain

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this article](https://css-tricks.com/five-methods-for-five-star-ratings/) from CSS Tricks (the last proposal there) i found another solution for showing only **!** the stars rating.
Assuming also a 5 star rating (average also possible).

Therefore you only need one div, that looks like this:

```
<div class="average-star-rating" style="--rating:{{$roundedNumber}};">
    </div>
```

The rest is done by the scss:

```
:root {
    --star-size: 30px;
    --star-off-color: #cccccc;
    --star-on-color: #fc0;
}

.average-star-rating {
    --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);

    display: inline-block;
    font-size: var(--star-size);
    font-family: Times; // make sure ★ appears correctly
    line-height: 1;

    &::before {
        content: "★★★★★";
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        background: linear-gradient(
            90deg,
            var(--star-on-color) var(--percent),
            var(--star-off-color) var(--percent)
        );
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

From your controller you simply need the rounded number. At the snippet i took 3.6.
You can simply replace the value with any number you want (in the snippet but naturally in your code too ;) ).

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z9fybLs/)